# How can I debug GraphQL subscriptions of a Django backend?

Tags: django, python-3.x, graphql, graphql-subscriptions, graphene-django

I'd like to add GraphQL subscriptions to a backend GraphQL API. Can I debug subscriptions with the `graphene_django` builtin GraphiQL?

```
# <django-project>/settings.py

...
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^graphql$', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
    ...,
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [graphene-subscriptions/issues/1](https://github.com/jaydenwindle/graphene-subscriptions/issues/1#issuecomment-563408705) it seems like it's possible to create a custom `GraphQLCustomCoreBackend`

```py
class GraphQLCustomCoreBackend(GraphQLCoreBackend):
    def __init__(self, executor=None):
        # type: (Optional[Any]) -> None
        super().__init__(executor)
        self.execute_params['allow_subscriptions'] = True
```

and include it with

```py
# <django-project>/urls.py

url_paths = [
    ...,
    path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(CustomGraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, backend=GraphQLCustomCoreBackend())), name='graphql'),
    ...,
]
```

to override the default one. However not tested yet.